# P5.js Get current fill/stroke color?

Tags: p5.js

I'm developing a addon library for p5.js and I need to setup several fill/stroke colors in certain functions.

Is there a way to get the current fill/stroke value so I can ensure that when the user calls said functions he doesn't have to worry about the colors that I set?

Something of this sort:

```js
function foo(){
    var tempColor = getFill();   //Hypothetical get color function 
    // ...
    fill(color1);                //Some color I use
    // ...
    fill(color2);                //Another color I use
    // ...
    fill(tempColor);             //Reset fill color to user set
}
```

Edit: Although undocumented, I found some references in p5.js to a curFillColor variable but I didn't find a way to use this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

P5.js is open source, so you can see exactly what they do when you call the `fill()` function [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/color/setting.js):

```
p5.prototype.fill = function() {
  this._renderer._setProperty('_fillSet', true);
  this._renderer._setProperty('_doFill', true);
  this._renderer.fill.apply(this._renderer, arguments);
  return this;
};
```

Which takes you to the renderer-specific `fill` variable. You can track that down, but basically: there isn't an easy way to get the current fill color.

What you might want to do is to use a buffer in your library. Don't call `fill()` on the main sketch; call `fill()` on the buffer. Do all your drawing to the buffer, and then draw that buffer to the sketch.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is the correct answer. Kinda odd that there is no specific function for this.

Comment: @Dozed12 I don't find it that odd. You're usually the one calling `fill()`, so if you need to keep track of it you can.

Answer (score 6):

Hey I don't know if its a bit late. I'm also trying to create an addon library for p5. So what I'm doing is I'm calling push just before I'm using the fill and after that call pop. So that I ensure that the fill is restored.

Refer
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push